# broken link for nav_view

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys ! It seems that the source link , ' Source: svn https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/navigation/trunk/nav_view '  for nav_view is broken at webpage, http://www.ros.org/wiki/nav_view .  The terminal states that
'svn: URL 'https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/navigation/trunk/nav_view' doesn't exist' .
Would you guys be kind enough to fix the link or perhaps provide me with a working link ? thanks a bunch !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11374/broken-link-for-nav_view/) by [bumblebee](https://answers.ros.org/users/1143/bumblebee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-09-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The nav_view package has been replaced by rviz and is no longer supported. The answer above provides links to some light-weight alternatives to rviz for interacting with the navigation stack. I've also updated the wiki page you referenced to reflect this: http://www.ros.org/wiki/nav_view

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although this does not directly answer your question, there are alternatives to nav_view.

University of Colorado at Boulder:

```
svn checkout http://prairiedog.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/nav_view_cu nav_view_cu-read-only
```

Stanford University:

```
svn co https://sail-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/sail-ros-pkg/trunk/semistable/visualization/nav_view_sdl nav_view_sdl
```

or [here](http://sail-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sail-ros-pkg/trunk/semistable/visualization/nav_view_sdl/?view=tar) for tarball.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-10-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1